# How to create clip-path between two images using CSS

Tags: html, css, image, svg

How do I recreate this mock-up using CSS? Its easy to create this using a layer mask in Photoshop but how do I recreate it using CSS?

It needs to be responsive so I'd rather code it than upload the image.

[image mock-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gDZ7.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bezier curve svg clip path is likely what you need, with two divs one with a higher z-index than the other.  This illustrates the technique, drawing your bezier curve might be best done in a graphics tool.

https://codesandbox.io/s/bezier-curve-clip-path-h8x8l?from-embed

You'll overlay a div with the clip path over the top, then set an opacity to it and a colour so it shines through.